# Retain focus on a record while switching between navigation subforms

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm beginning to develop a UI for various departments in my office to support the viewing and editing of customer records.

I have a navigation form with each tab being a separate table within the database. One is customer specific info like SSN, first/last name, etc. The next would be address, the following is contact info, orders, etc.

The first form is where they select the customer. All following forms will depend upon who they select here. I need to be able to retain the `Record ID` from the first form as they navigate elsewhere. Currently, the form resets each time it loses focus.

Is there a way to enable this? The following forms will be filtered according to what they select in the first couple.

Comment: Might have to set a global variable or use TempVars. I advise not to use Navigation form. I don't like it and have never used. I put subforms on a Tab control. Forms can be nest 7 levels. Also review http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the difference between a nav form and table controls. I was under the impression that nav forms improved load times so that's why I went with them.

Comment: Tab not table control. Yes, nav forms are supposed to be faster on initial opening because only one subform is actually open at a time. This is what can make it difficult to reference subforms if you want to reference one from another. Whereas with a tab control, all the subforms are loaded. But is this so much slower it causes noticeable performance issue? Depends on size and complexity of form/subform(s) arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `Record ID` in the Form's Tag property.

Then:

- If loading a new form, you can pass it to the form's `.OpenArgs` property.
- If loading a subform, you can get it through the `.Parent.Tag` property.

User selects a record:

```
  Me.Tag = Me![Record ID]
```

Opening a new form:

```
'Open form
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmName", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal, Me.Tag

'Filter Form
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Me
        If Not IsNull(.OpenArgs) Then
            .Filter = "[Record  ID]=" & .OpenArgs
            .FilterOn = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Loading a subform:

```
'Filter Form
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Me
        If Not IsNull(.Parent.Tag) Then
            .Filter = "[Record  ID]=" & .Parent.Tag
            .FilterOn = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Lastly, if navigating between forms, store it in each form's Tag property.

Comment: So use main form Tag property like a global variable? Would this work with Navigation form? Or are you suggesting a normal form/subform and loading different subforms into same container control?

Comment: @June7 Assuming one form (at least) will always be loaded, we can use its .Tag property as a global variable. Be either a simple parent/child or browsing between different single forms. Similar to TempVar but easier in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Although not implemented with the navigation form, an article and a full demo on syncing subforms is here:

[Synchronizing Multiple Subforms in Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18107/Synchronizing-Multiple-Subforms-in-Access.html)

Comment: A better source for that article http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Comment: Source? I wrote the referenced article. But as I understand the questioneer, the subforms are filtered the same, thus _syncing_ it needed when browsing these, while the FMS article is about (sub)_filtering_. However, I never use the navigation form, so I may have missed something.

Comment: Okay, haven't visited Experts Exchange in a long time. I quit visiting when it required me to become a paying member in order to view forum threads. Didn't go past the popup that appeared when I first opened that link, not realizing it was a free article. I didn't pay attention to author names. Don't know if someone copied someone or just great minds thinking alike. But sometimes same concept stated just a bit different can help get the message over. And I think the FMS article does discuss the technique of a textbox on main form to serve as linking criteria but does not require VBA.

Comment: OK. But syncing two or more subforms normally means that _selecting a record in one subform forces the current records on the non-current subform(s) to follow the ID of the current record on the current subform._

Comment: I got the impression poster's subforms are bound to different table sources but wants 'parent' and 'child' and 'grandchild' side-by-side (or on tabs) so all can be continuous view forms.